# From apply to purrr's pmap

Tags: r, purrr

I'm currently switching my apply functions to purrr. I've had help with a couple commands, but as soon as a degree of complexity is added, I'm thrown for a loop. I'm wondering what the purrr alternative is to the code below. The goal is to find the most recent year a score was registered, for each row, using the column names. Once again, I give the functional (apply) code.

```
dat = data.frame('SCORE_2010'=c(0,0,1,0),'SCORE_2011'=c(1,0,1,0),'SCORE_2012'=c(0,0,1,0),'SCORE_2013'=c(1,0,0,1))

dat[,'L_YEAR'] = apply(dat[,grepl('^SCORE_[0-9]+',names(dat))],
                       1,
                       function(x) 
                         ifelse(length(which(x==1))>0,str_extract(names(dat)[max(which(x==1))],'[0-9]+'),0)
                       )
```

Comment: What's do you find missing with `*apply`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's bad, it's just the code is ugly and I have to break up my dplyr statements to fit them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
dat %>%
   mutate(L_YEAR = pmap(., ~ c(...) %>% 
               {names(which(. == 1)) %>% 
               last %>%
               parse_number}))
```

An option would be `max.col`

```
library(readr)
parse_number(names(dat)[max.col(dat, 'last') * NA^(!rowSums(dat > 0))])
#[1] 2013   NA 2012 2013
```

Comment: What if we included columns without 'SCORE_xxxx' and wanted to select only 'SCORE_xxxx' columns, create the variable L_YEAR and add it to the original set?

Comment: @chachimouchacha  In that case, you can do `pmap(select(., starts_with("SCORE"), ~`

Comment: @chachimouchacha  It would be  `dat %>% mutate(L_YEAR = pmap(select(., starts_with("SCORE")), ~ c(...) %>%  {names(which(. == 1)) %>% 
                last %>%
                parse_number} ))`

Comment: Thanks so much, akrun! You've been great help.